# @gmail not accepting while sql selection using petapoco

Tags: c#, petapoco

I have an SQL select statement as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUL_USERS WHERE EMAIL='entityframework@gmail.com' AND CUST_ID=1 AND TRASH=0
```

but it is throwing an error as:

> Parameter '@gmail' specified but none of the passed arguments have a
>   property with this name

I have also tried to email as 'entityframework@@gmail.com' but didn't work.

What does the error message implies? What is wrong with the SQL statement? Does `petaPOCO` not accept `@` in an SQL statement? I need to do a search by email address.

Comment: Please provide some context to your question so that ppl can better understand what you are trying to do. This way, it is also easier for them to spot what your issue might be. For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _"I have also tried to email as 'entityframework@@gmail.com' but didn't work"_ - that should work. Explain why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Using double `@@` it's the way to go. (Must be something else that's giving you an error)

Other thing you can do it's using a parameter

```
db.SingleOrDefault<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALL_USERS 
     WHERE EMAIL=@0 AND CUST_ID=1 AND TRASH=0", "entityframework@gmail.com")
```